# What is the flux linkage or inductance or induced voltage per unit length of the hollow tube conductor surrounding the inner conductor?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

What is the flux linkage or inductance or induced voltage per unit length of the hollow tube conductor surrounding the inner conductor in some section due to the current in the inner thin conductor?

Corner effects, etc. are not taken into account.

[image]